# Django - Confirmation popup

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to write a code for deleting an item. But before deleting it i want to popup a message to the user like "are you sure you want to delete?".
I want to delete the item by its ID.

I wrote this code, but i pretty sure its not how it should be.

Please guide me what to do.

**HTML FILE**

```
 <div id="film_box">
 {% if films %}
 {% for film in films %}
 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  {% if film.image%}
 <img src="{{ film.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
{% endif %}
 <div class="card-body">
 <h5 class="card-title">{{ film.title}}</h5>
 <p class="card-text">{{ film.category_name }}</p>
 <p class="card-text">{{ film.country_name }}</p>
 <p class="card-text">{{ film.director }}</p>
 <p class="card-text">{{ film.release_date }}</p>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
  {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
  <ul style="list-style:none;">
 <li><a href="{% url 'update_director' film.director_id %}" class="card-link">Modify the director</a> 
 </li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'update_film' film.id %}" class="card-link">Modify the film</a></li>
  <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('btn_delete').style.display='block'"
              name="{{ film.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button></li>
 </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

```
<!--popup message-->
<div id="btn_delete" class="modal">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('btn_delete').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close 
Modal">×</span>
 <form class="modal-content" action="/delete/{{film.id}}">
 <div class="container">
   <h1>Delete film</h1>
   <p>Are you sure you want to delete the film?</p> 

   <div class="clearfix">
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('btn_delete').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <button href="{% url 'delete_film' film.id %}" onclick="document.getElementById('btn_delete').style.display='none'" class="deletebtn">Delete</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
</div>
{% endfor%}
{% endif %}
```

**JAVASCRIPT FILE**

```
   // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('btn_delete');
 console.log(model.name)
 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

I want to pass the ID in the url, so i can catch it on the python file and manipulate it.
Should i use Javascript?

Comment: Yeah, you can use JavaScript for that

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. Please note the code is not tested, however the principles should give you a glimpse of understanding of how to proper do it.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import generic


# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^delete/(?P<pk>.+)/$', views.DeleteFilmView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]


# models.py
class Film(models.Model):
    # ...

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('film:delete', args=(self.pk,))


# views.py
class DeleteFilmView(generic.DeleteView):
    template_name = 'delete_confirmation.html'
    model = Film
    context_object_name = 'film'

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'messages': 'Deleted'})


<!--html file--> 

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Film</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="film_box">
    {% if films %}
    {% for film in films %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        {% if film.image%}
            <img src="{{ film.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ film.title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ film.category_name }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ film.country_name }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ film.director }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ film.release_date }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                <ul style="list-style:none;">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'update_director' film.director_id %}" class="card-link">Modify the director</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'update_film' film.id %}" class="card-link">Modify the film</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="{{ film.delete }}" class="deletePopup">Delete</a></li>

                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        $('.deletePopup').on('click',function(){
            $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){
                $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
            });
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.delete-film', function(e) {
            // make sure you listen on the body and not on the element, because the element doesnt exist when 
            // DOM is created.
            e.preventDefault():
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('href');,
                type: 'DELETE',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                    // show success message, ie: using toastr
                    // remove the film from DOM
                    // close the modal
                }
            })
        })

    })();
</script>


<!--delete_confirmation.html--> 
<p>Are you sure you want to delete {{ film.title}}?</p>

<a class="delete-film" href="{{ film.get_delete_url }}">Delete</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-dismiss="modal" href="_blank"> Cancel</a>
```

Comment: Cool, looks a little complicated. hope it will work

Comment: @E.Bolandian It's very simple, actually. DeleteView, on GET returns a rendered html (delete confirmation content), thats why deletePopup button on click is calling the url and will be loaded into modal's body, modal will open with the confirmation content and when user will press Delete, an XHR call is performed to the same DeleteView, just the method is DELETE now, which will trigger the objection deletion action. You should use Django CCBV http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/ cheatsheet to understand how views are working.